# How Can I show alertbox in c# using jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two dropdown lists, both of them listing the same countries. I want to display an alert message when the user selects the same country on both dropdowns. How can I do that using jQuery?

```
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %>").change(function () {

         if ($("#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%> option:selected").text() == $("#<%=ddlCountry1.ClientID%> option:selected").text()) 
             {
                 alert("Please select different countries");
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the generated code? C# has nothing to do with this.

Comment: JQuery and C# are not related. What are you talking about??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your dropdownlist has an autopostback set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it is basically on the right track. Except for 2 things:

1. You should detect the change event on both dropdowns.
2. Assuming the values and text of the dropdown options will be the same in both, you just need to check the .val() of each.

The end result would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlCountry, #ddlCountry1').on('change', function() {
        if ( $('#ddlCountry').val() === $('#ddlCountry1').val() ) {
            alert('Please select different countries');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code don't have any so issues but try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %>, #<%=ddlCountry1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        if ($("#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %> option:selected").val() == $("#<%=ddlCountry1.ClientID %> option:selected").val())
        {
            alert("Please select different countries");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to show dialog window? If so, you can see the code below. You can check out the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).
Also, you need to check both dropdowns when the selection is changed.

```
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %>").change(function() {
        if ($("#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%> option:selected").text() == $("#<%=ddlCountry1.ClientID%> option:selected").text()) {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  dialogClass: "no-close",
  buttons: [
    {
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  ]
});
        }
    });
});

</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Alert">
    <p>Please select different countries</p>
</div>`
```

Comment: just code is not an answer, please see [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)